# Как складывать значения аргумента?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, есть ли способ правильно складывать прошлые значения аргументов с новыми?

Код:

```
const TAX = 73;

function getTax (buy) {
  let discount = buy / 100 * TAX;
    return discount;
}

console.log(getTax(9000));
console.log(getTax(18000));
console.log(getTax(27000));
console.log(getTax(36000));
console.log(`Налог с продаж (${TAX} %), к оплате: ${getTax()} Q`);
```

В `console.log(`Налог с продаж (${TAX} %), к оплате: ${getTax()} Q`);` мне надо получить сумму всех уже раннее указанных аргументов, то есть, попросту сложить значения раннее вычисленных значений аргумента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вроде называется мемоизация или как то так. Вам надо положить куда-то промежуточную сумму, например в замыкание, как то так -

```js
const TAX = 73;

const getTax = (() => {
    let sum = 0;
    return (buy=0) => {
      sum += buy / 100 * TAX;
      return sum;
    }
})()

console.log(getTax(9000));
console.log(getTax(18000));
console.log(getTax(27000));
console.log(getTax(36000));
console.log(`Налог с продаж (${TAX} %), к оплате: ${getTax()} Q`);
```

И есть еще миллион способов сделать это по другому)

Comment: Спасибо большое :)